# WordPress widget not displaying on the front

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Have a custom widget using the class API structure that will not display on the front end. The data collected is being stored in the database and updated via wp-admin. When viewed through the customizer the widget is greyed out with opacity and is being rendered on the front end. I can't see where it's going wrong:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args );

    echo $args['before_widget'];
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $description = empty( $instance['description'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['description'];
    if( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; }

    echo '<div class="cjd">';
    echo '<input type="text" class="email" name="cjd-email"/>';
    echo '<input type="button" class="subscribe-button" name="subscribe" value="'. _e( 'Add your email', 'cjd') .'" />';
    echo '</div>';
    echo $args['after_widget'];

}
```

Code Calling the widget:

```
 function cjd_subscribe_widget() {
    $widget_ops = array( 
        'classname' => 'cjd-widget', 
        'description' => __( 'Adds a input form allowing newsletter subscription.', 'cjd' )
    );

    $this->WP_Widget( 'cjd_subscribe_widget', 'CJD: ' . __( 'Client Subscribe', 'cjd' ), $widget_ops );
}
```

Widget registration:

```
function cjd_register_widgets() {
register_widget( 'cjd_subscribe_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'cjd_register_widgets' );
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is supposed to be calling this method

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Turns out I had placed the widget in a is_admin() function call. once outside the widget was displaying. Thanks @JH

Comment: I really thank you for this I was banging my head since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register the widget before you can use it.

```
class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {

function MyNewWidget() {
    // Instantiate the parent object
    parent::__construct( false, 'My New Widget Title' );
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // Widget output
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    // Save widget options
}

function form( $instance ) {
    // Output admin widget options form
}
}

function myplugin_register_widgets() {
register_widget( 'MyNewWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

and in your functions.php file:

```
register_widget( $widget_class );
```

[Function Reference with Wordpress Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget)

**EDIT**

Try calling the widget like [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget):

```
<?php the_widget( $widget, $instance, $args ); ?>
```

Comment: I get: Notice: Undefined index: cjd_subscribe_widget through the widgets.php on line 1554. No errors are being outputted through the console either.

Comment: @jamper create the class, create the constructor, when you register the widget, register by the class name, not the function

Comment: I've just changed the theme and dumped in a demo widget which I know works and it doesn't want to display either of them. I think the problem maybe WordPress related??